How can I fix the frozen terminal during installation?
I'm trying to install Gforth from this page
I tried both installing from GitHub and from tarball.
In both cases just before the last step, e.g. after entering ./configure on the tarball install, after some activity and a few warnings, the cursor starts to blink and nothing happens. Usually when install is finished it should go to the prompt, but it doesn't.
I include the last screenshot where the cursor blinks and nothing happens.
I waited a few hours for something to happen, but nothing happened.
I'm on MacOS Sonoma 14.2, Intel
EDIT 6 Aug
This is the latest error I get:
a@As-MacBook-Air gforth-0.7.9_20240801 % sudo make install
Password:
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim.b] Error 72

EDIT
I tried to install to an M1 Mac and I got this error:
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim-fast.b] Error 72

This is strange Xcode developer tools are installed and m4 folder is in the gforth directory.
I guess I give up.
EDIT
The file that has the code that stops the install has this warning:

\ WARNING: This file is processed by m4. Make sure your identifiers 
don't collide with m4's (e.g. by undefining them). \

This may be the cause. Do you know how I can open that .m4 file?
.m4 file is here. Doesn't seem to be related to the error.
EDIT
I found the line that gives error in the source here (line 3392)

__atomic_compare_exchange_n(a_addr, &uprev, unew, 0,
          __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);


Can it be corrupted line?
EDIT
This is the dump from the terminal:
a@As-MacBook-Air gforth-0.7.9_20240801 % ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /opt/homebrew/bin/gsed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin23.5.0 file names to aarch64-apple-darwin23.5.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin23.5.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for file... file
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
no
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin23.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for gcc options needed to detect all undeclared functions... none needed
checking what extension is used for runtime loadable modules... .so
checking what variable specifies run-time module search path... DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
checking for the default library search path... /usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib
checking for library containing dlopen... none required
checking for dlerror... yes
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dld_link in -ldld... no
checking for _ prefix in compiled symbols... yes
checking whether we have to add an underscore for dlsym... no
checking whether deplibs are loaded by dlopen... yes
checking for argz.h... no
checking for error_t... no
checking for argz_add... no
checking for argz_append... no
checking for argz_count... no
checking for argz_create_sep... no
checking for argz_insert... no
checking for argz_next... no
checking for argz_stringify... no
checking whether libtool supports -dlopen/-dlpreopen... yes
checking for ltdl.h... no
checking where to find libltdl headers... -I$(top_srcdir)/libltdl
checking where to find libltdl library... $(top_build_prefix)libltdl/libltdlc.la
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for dl.h... no
checking for sys/dl.h... no
checking for dld.h... no
checking for mach-o/dyld.h... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for closedir... yes
checking for opendir... yes
checking for readdir... yes
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for  option for large files... none needed
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether to use two dispatches per conditional branch... 1
checking make type... GNU Make
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,--export-dynamic... no
checking for __builtin___clear_cache... yes
checking for __builtin_add_overflow... yes
Check for arch/arm64//gforth.ld (false)
checking size of char *... 8
checking size of void *... 8
checking size of char... 1
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of intptr_t... 8
checking size of __int128_t... 16
checking size of __uint128_t... 16
checking for a C type for cells... long
checking for a C type for wydes... short
checking for a C type for tetrabytes... int
checking for a C type for octabytes... long
checking for a C type for double-cells... __int128_t
checking for a C type for unsigned double-cells... __uint128_t
checking for off_t... yes
checking size of off_t... 8
checking if gcc understands -fno-gcse... yes
checking if gcc understands -fcaller-saves... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-defer-pop... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-inline... yes
checking if gcc understands -fwrapv... yes
checking if gcc understands -fchar-unsigned... no
checking if gcc understands -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-cse-follow-jumps... no
checking if gcc understands -fno-reorder-blocks... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-reorder-blocks-and-partition... no
checking if gcc understands -fno-toplevel-reorder... no
checking if gcc understands -fno-trigraphs... yes
checking if gcc understands -falign-labels=1... yes
checking if gcc understands -falign-loops=1... yes
checking if gcc understands -falign-jumps=1... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks... yes
checking if gcc understands -fcf-protection=none... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-tree-vectorize... yes
checking if gcc understands -fno-lto... yes
checking if gcc understands -mllvm=--tail-dup-indirect-size=0... no
checking if gcc understands -pthread... yes
checking if gcc understands -Wimplicit-function-declaration... yes
checking how to suppress 'unused variable' warnings... __attribute__((unused))
checking whether gcc understands '__thread'... yes
checking how to invoke m4... m4
checking for install-info... /opt/local/bin/install-info
checking if gcc understands -no-cpp-precomp on Darwin... yes
checking for chcon... true
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking if and how we can waste code space... .skip 16
checking if and how we can do comments in asm statements... "# "
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... mkdir -p
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for texi2dvi4a2ps... no
checking for texi2dvi... texi2dvi
checking for tex... tex
checking for recode... no
checking for iconv... iconv
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for texi2html... no
checking for timeout... no
checking for emacs... no
checking for xemacs... no
configure: WARNING: No emacs found, won't build gforth.elc.
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking for glibtool... glibtool
checking for asin in -lm... yes
checking for lt_dlinit in -lltdl... no
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... no
checking for dlopen... yes
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi/ffi.h... yes
checking for ffi_call in -lffi... yes
checking for __builtin_avcall in -lavcall... no
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for exp10... no
checking for sincos... no
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strsignal... yes
checking for atanh... yes
checking for declarations of fseeko and ftello... yes
checking for ftello... yes
checking for sys_siglist... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for stack_t... yes
checking whether sys_siglist is declared... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking for expm1... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking for mcheck... no
checking for mprobe... no
checking for rint... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... no
checking for fnmatch.h... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... (cached) yes
checking for endian.h... no
checking for spawn.h... yes
checking for wcwidth... yes
checking for working POSIX fnmatch... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for pselect... yes
checking for pthread_setaffinity_np... no
checking for getentropy... yes
checking for getrandom... no
checking for emacs... no
checking for xemacs... no
checking where .elc files should go... ${datadir}/emacs/site-lisp
checking for __builtin_clzl... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap16... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap32... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap64... yes
checking for legacy atomic builtins (__sync_...)... true
checking for atomic builtins (__atomic_...)... true
lispdir=
elispstartdir=
checking for gforth... /opt/homebrew/bin/gforth: image kernl64l.fi doesn't seem to be a Gforth (>=0.6) image.
"/opt/homebrew/bin/gforth" -i "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gforth/0.7.3_3/lib/gforth/0.7.3/gforth.fi"
checking for swig-forth... no
checking for swig... no
configure: WARNING: *** Could not find swig in your PATH. The library bindings cannot be built.
./configure: line 19981: -forth: command not found
checking for X11/X.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/Xrandr.h... yes
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for GL/glext.h... yes
checking for glXCreateWindow in -lGLX... no
checking for glClear in -lGLESv2... yes
checking for GLES2/gl2.h... yes
checking for GLES2/gl2ext.h... yes
checking for EGL/egl.h... no
checking for libpng16/png.h... yes
checking for stb/stb_image.h... no
checking for stb/stb_image_write.h... no
checking for ft2build.h... yes
checking for FT_Get_Char_Index in -lfreetype... yes
checking for freetype-gl.h... yes
checking for resvg.h... no
Package wayland-client was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `wayland-client.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'wayland-client' found
checking for wl_egl_window_create in -lwayland-egl... no
checking for gps_open in -lgps... no
Package harfbuzz was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `harfbuzz.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'harfbuzz' found
checking for hb_buffer_create in -lharfbuzz... no
checking for hb_buffer_get_direction in -lharfbuzz... no
checking for pa_context_new in -lpulse... no
Package libspa-0.2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libspa-0.2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libspa-0.2' found
Package libpipewire-0.3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpipewire-0.3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libpipewire-0.3' found
checking for pw_main_loop_new in -lpipewire-0.3... no
Package xkbcommon was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xkbcommon.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xkbcommon' found
checking for xkb_keymap_new_from_buffer in -lxkbcommon... no
checking for opus_encode in -lopus... no
configure: WARNING: *** Swig without -forth. Building library buildings  x.fs xrandr.fs gles.fs png16.fs freetype_gl.fs from tarball.
SWIG includes: -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 
checking for utf8 locale... nl_NL.UTF-8
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... -std=gnu++11
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++11 -E
checking for ld used by g++ -std=gnu++11... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the g++ -std=gnu++11 linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ -std=gnu++11 option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if g++ -std=gnu++11 PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ -std=gnu++11 static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ -std=gnu++11 supports -c -o file.o... rm: conftest*: No such file or directory
yes
checking if g++ -std=gnu++11 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ -std=gnu++11 linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking if g++ -std=gnu++11 understands -fpermissive... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating kernel/version.fs
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating Makedist
config.status: creating gforthmi
config.status: creating gforthmi.sh
config.status: creating vmgen
config.status: creating machpc.fs
config.status: creating envos.fs
config.status: creating preforth
config.status: creating libforth
config.status: creating gforthker
config.status: creating engine/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'engine/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating engine/gforth.h
config.status: creating doc/version.texi
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating unix/Makefile
config.status: creating unix/wayland.i
config.status: creating debian/changelog
config.status: creating debian/control
config.status: creating debian/rules
config.status: creating docker/runner/Dockerfile
config.status: creating build-ec
config.status: creating engine/config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
rm: libtoolT: No such file or directory
config.status: executing stamp-h commands
checking for cowsay... no
checking for lolcat... no

*** Config summary: Warnings exist ***

texi2html not found, HTML document won't be built.
swig not found.
Swig without -forth feature, library interfaces will not be generated.
a@As-MacBook-Air gforth-0.7.9_20240801 % make
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o io.o io.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o signals.o signals.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o arm64-cacheflush.o arm64-cacheflush.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o exp10.o exp10.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o sincos.o sincos.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -DFORCE_LL -o support-ll.o support.c
support.c:133:18: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is treated as a zero-parameter prototype in C2x, conflicting with a previous declaration [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
  struct passwd *getpwnam (), *user_entry;
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pwd.h:101:16: note: conflicting prototype is here
struct passwd   *getpwnam(const char *);
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o support-noll.o support.c
support.c:133:18: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is treated as a zero-parameter prototype in C2x, conflicting with a previous declaration [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
  struct passwd *getpwnam (), *user_entry;
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pwd.h:101:16: note: conflicting prototype is here
struct passwd   *getpwnam(const char *);
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -DFORCE_LL -DFORCE_REG -o support-ll-reg.o support.c
support.c:133:18: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is treated as a zero-parameter prototype in C2x, conflicting with a previous declaration [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
  struct passwd *getpwnam (), *user_entry;
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pwd.h:101:16: note: conflicting prototype is here
struct passwd   *getpwnam(const char *);
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -DFORCE_REG -o support-noll-reg.o support.c
support.c:133:18: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is treated as a zero-parameter prototype in C2x, conflicting with a previous declaration [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
  struct passwd *getpwnam (), *user_entry;
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pwd.h:101:16: note: conflicting prototype is here
struct passwd   *getpwnam(const char *);
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o dblsub.o dblsub.c
Makefile:218: target `libgforth.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:222: target `libgforth-fast.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:226: target `libgforth-itc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:230: target `libgforth-ditc.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:234: target `libgforth-prof.la' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:238: target `libgforth-fi.la' given more than once in the same rule.
CC -o libmain.o libmain.c
CROSS kernl64l.fi

Compiling wheres
undefined UADDR
undefined prelude-mask
undefined [compile]
undefined prelude-mask
undefined [compile]
undefined [compile]
undefined UTO
undefined UTO
undefined UTO
set image entry point

Unresolved: Nothing!

address-space      Start: 0000.0000  End: 0000.0000  DP: 0000.0000 
user-region        Start: 0000.6C10  End: 0000.7410  DP: 0000.6D28 
dictionary         Start: 0000.0100  End: 0080.0100  DP: 0006.FA88 
return-stack       Start: 0000.0000  End: 0000.0000  DP: 0000.0000 
data-stack         Start: 0000.0000  End: 0000.0000  DP: 0000.0000 
tib-region         Start: 0000.0000  End: 0000.0000  DP: 0000.0000 Saving to kernl64l.fi-
CC-ENGINE-DITC -o engine-ditc-noll.o engine.c
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fno-gcse' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fcaller-saves' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fno-defer-pop' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fno-reorder-blocks' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-labels=1' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-jumps=1' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
In file included from ./engine.c:661:
prim:3394:37: warning: passing 'UCell *' (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'Cell *' (aka 'long *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
__atomic_compare_exchange_n(a_addr, &uprev, unew, 0,
                                    ^~~~~~


please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... post all of the message

Ok. The screen is gone now. I'll try to install again and copy the text. But this is pages and pages long. There is Homebrew updating, probably you don't need those.

@jsotola Ok, I added the terminal starting with ./configure to the end. After the last line cursor blinks but nothing happens. Thanks.

The message about __atomic_compare_exchange_n is only a warning. It is not the problem root.   Try to fill a bugreport at Gforth - Bugs

@ruvim Thanks. I filed a bug a report in the link you supplied.

By the way, I don't see your bug report right now. Was your problem solved?

@ruvim No, they were very helpful but we couldn't solve it. It seems that the problem is about clang conflicting with gcc. The bug report is closed but the link is this https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?66066. Maybe you don't see it because it is closed? I also asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78847785/how-can-i-stop-apple-s-compiler-clang-impersonating-gcc
